# Is GNOME broken in 11.10?

Tags: gnome

Me and my friend both installed GNOME on 11.10 I have problem that I cant left click on top bar, middle click also doesnt work. My friend gets weird tiny light blue boxes in GUI...
So is GNOME broken in 11.10 or we just have bad luck? OH and PCs arent similar, His is AMD/ATI laptop, mine is Intel/nV desktop

EDIT: to make it clearer:
I use gnome classic, and right click on top bar wont work... you know add to panel.... that menu behaves like it doesnt exist. My friend fixed his problem in GNOME 3 by going bact to open source driver.  But he still cant right click on top bar on GNOME classic.

Comment: Ok, first of all Ubuntu 11.10 uses Unity, second Gnome Shell is a different enviroment than Unity, BOTH use Gnome 3, and no there's no "classic" anymore, that's the Gnome Shell fallback mode which is similar to the Gnome 2 panel interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you boot in GNOME 3 in fallback mode (what you call GNOME Classic) it would look like GNOME 2 but it won't be GNOME 2 and you won't be able to add applets and there is no right click on panels (nothing happen if you do a right click on panels) but you can do a Alt+RightClick on it to access it's properties dialog.

I suggest you try using GNOME shell, it's hard to use at first but you'll get used to it in no time.

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't.

It has a lot of problems with closed ATI drivers, probably that explains what happens in your friends PC. It should work for him disabling Catalyst, going back to the open source drivers.

I'm in the same situation: ATI laptop, and Gnome Shell not working. I think (I have read) the problem is in the drivers, not in Unity, so I hope ATI to fix it. I am not very optimistic about it happening soon either.

EDITED:
I have no idea about why could it be failing for your nVidia anyway. Is it an old GPU? May be it's also a problem with drivers, Gnome-Shell is a little picky about that. You could try newer experimental drivers.

Answer (score 3):

By gnome, do you mean you're logging into the gnome-shell? The default manager is Unity in 11.10, and this does not support right click. If you're in the gnome shell, I believe you use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse2 to bring up applet menus, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse2.

Answer (score 0):

Installing "advanced settings" package on Ubuntu 11.10 using software center will install gnome classic ,gnome 3 etc packages.

I have installed it to just to switch between various icon themes.But later noticed it had automatically installed gnome classic package.